# Tag merging academy

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

*First of all, a discussion in chat has brought us these ideas that **if there's a tag to be discussed about, why not a single post that covers all?** Please comment on this post and let me know if such thing is acceptable by the community. The idea of this post is to firstly discuss the possibility of having such general post, in which the repliers speak of the tags they think are troublesome.*

---

The sole purpose of this post is to primarily discuss deletion or synonymization of the two tags known as [opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) and [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison), and then discuss if whether it's appropriate to have a single whole post as the discussion zone for tag removals. Please downvote in accordance to the agreement/disagreement about the removal of the two tags above. I'll edit it out if I see that the community sees no benefit in having a whole and general post for such cause. So here goes:

I (and some of other fellows) see no reason to keep tags like the two mentioned above. It would be kind of any answerer who sees keeping [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) along with [word-choice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) superior to merging it with the tag bring up their reasons. The same goes for [opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) as it would be better if it was merged into [antonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms), in my opinion. What do *you* think?

---

Just to sum things up, here are the mergers I'm proposing so far:

- [opposite-word](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite-word) → [antonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonyms)
- [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) → [word-choice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)

---

Comment: Oh I really should read the tag wikis more often. I always thought [tag:comparison] was about [morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_(grammar) "Wikipedia: Comparison (grammar)"), not choosing between two phrases or words.

Comment: @ColleenV, should there be a post that will contain future tag discussions? I mean, a single post that covers all?

Comment: @ColleenV This is tangential, but: English has both morphological ("better") and syntactic ("more beautiful") comparatives.  The former is often called inflectional, while the latter is usually called periphrastic or analytic. The same goes for superlatives ("best" and "most beautiful"). In any case, it's not just a matter of morphology.

Comment: @snailboat I admit I simplified it quite a bit because my understanding of the terminology is limited. I just thought the tag was more linguistically relevant than it is described as in the wiki because I know that there are ways of forming comparative and superlative constructions in different languages even though I don't much detail. I shouldn't assume I know what a tag means just by looking at it :)

Answer (score 1):

I read https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms, but I could not understand it.  Currently, an ELL user needs an ELL-level reputation of 1250, plus a score of 5 in the tag, to suggest tag synonyms.

- Is that 50 reputation in the tag? or 5 reputation in the tag?
- Is that in the tag to be obscured, or in the tag that survives?

Comment: I believe it means five upvotes in the master tag.

Comment: I though I was the only one that was baffled about what was written there!

Answer (score 1):

[Tag Overflow](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=ell) shows [how tags are related, or need work.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2378)

Comment: How will it tell us if we should merge a tag or not? Besides, we have to make sure the community completely agrees with the removals of the tags and that's why we post these things on meta.

Comment: @MARamezani -- You are correct on all three points; it does not provide enough information to make a decision.  But it can show us tags to look into.  For example, if one tag is only used with another tag, we might notice the relationship in Tag Overflow.  Tag Overflow can also highlight tags that have high percentages of unanswered questions.